# Can't set cookies in Plug in test

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a plug who's responsibility is to fetch a cookie from the request which is a token and verify it.

I am currently having issue setting up my tests to pass a cookie inside the conn.

```
  setup do
    token = "some string"
    conn =
      conn(:get, "/")
      |> put_req_cookie("session_token", token)

    %{conn: MyPlug.call(conn, [])}
  end

  test "user passes through when token is valid", %{conn: conn} do
    require IEx; IEx.pry

    assert conn.status == 200
  end
```

In my debugger if I check `conn.cookies`
I get `%Plug.Conn.Unfetched{aspect: :cookies}`.

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 4):

`put_req_cookie` only adds a `cookie` header to the `conn` struct. You need to call `Plug.Conn.fetch_cookies` after that to parse the cookie headers and load them into the `cookies` map. The following code should work:

```
conn =
  conn(:get, "/")
  |> put_req_cookie("session_token", token)
  |> fetch_cookies()
```